# How to get IoT topic when redirecting to SQS in AWS

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-iot

Is there any way I can get topic name in SQS queue when messages were redirected from AWS IoT?

Comment: Can you show us what you receive, now, and the query that creates it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the sql function topic() in the SELECT statement of the IOT rule.

Something like

`SELECT * as data, topic() as topic FROM 'your topic'`

IOT sql function reference http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-function-topic

Comment: I tried the same thing. I am using a lambda function to extract the topic name and processing the payload in the lambda function.  The topic name is extracted correctly in the lambda function but the complete payload is not received in the lambda function.  I am using the method sqsEvent.Records[0].Body to extract the payload.

Comment: The above works great for me! @Dattatray I'm not using Lambda, but doing this: ```const decodedMessage = JSON.parse(message.Body);
  const { topic, payload } = decodedMessage;```